# vimtex: how to switch latex engine dynamically

Tags: plugin-vimtex, compile-vim

I now use vimtex to edit my latex source files.
Usually, I use the xelatex engine.
So I have the following line at the beginning of my `.tex` file.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
```

Sometimes I need to switch the engine.
I think it is not very convenient to edit this line and reload vim every time when switch the engine.

Are there some method, e.g. `\pdf` or `\lua`, to make vimtex to switch the engine to pdflatex or lualatex dynamically?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes I need to switch the engine.

You can do it like this:

0. For convenience, ensure that you've stopped compilation of the document.
   When you change the engine, it is probably also smart to clean auxiliary
   files.
1. Change the line, e.g. to `%! TeX Program = lualatex`.
2. Run `:VimtexReload` (mapped to `\lx` by default).

Comment: After reading the help file it seems the map setting works. `nnoremap \lua :let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines['_']  = '-lualatex'<CR> :VimtexCompile<CR>`. Is it a good choice to set `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines`?

Comment: I don't quite see why you want to change the engine all the time. I would just specify your desired default (with `g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines` as you already figured out), then use the TeX directive if you want to use a different engine in a specific document.